# iOS geocodeAddressString returns null value for postalCode

Tags: ios, geocoding

I'm calling geocodeAddressString with a city name (e.g. Seattle, Los Angeles, etc.). In the Xcode simulator, this returns a single correct placemark value, but no postalCode:

```
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:placename completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    //Error checking
    NSLog(@"placemarks %i",[placemarks count]);

    if ([placemarks count] == 1) { // one city returned. set location accordingly
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"one location found %@",placemark);
        [self setUserLocation:placemark];
    } 

}];
```

Output placemark values:

```
- (void)setUserLocation:(CLPlacemark *)placemark {
  NSLog(@"found zip %@",placemark.postalCode);
  NSLog(@"found city %@",placemark.locality);
  NSLog(@"found state %@",placemark.administrativeArea);
  NSLog(@"found country %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);
  NSLog(@"found lat %f",placemark.region.center.latitude);
  NSLog(@"found long %f",placemark.region.center.longitude);
}
```

Shows the following:

```
2014-05-21 07:28:12.378 jobagent[5157:60b] entered location seattle
2014-05-21 07:28:12.378 jobagent[5157:60b] placename seattle
2014-05-21 07:28:12.992 jobagent[5157:60b] placemarks 1
2014-05-21 07:28:12.993 jobagent[5157:60b] one location found Seattle, WA, United States @   <+47.60620950,-122.33207080> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+47.56346943,-122.32853603> radius 26395.84', center:<+47.56346943,-122.32853603>, radius:26395.84m)
2014-05-21 07:28:12.993 jobagent[5157:60b] found zip (null)
2014-05-21 07:28:12.994 jobagent[5157:60b] found city Seattle
2014-05-21 07:28:12.994 jobagent[5157:60b] found state WA
2014-05-21 07:28:12.995 jobagent[5157:60b] found country US
2014-05-21 07:28:12.995 jobagent[5157:60b] found lat 47.563469
2014-05-21 07:28:12.996 jobagent[5157:60b] found long -122.328536
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLGeocoder` doesn't return the `postalCode` for just a City, because there are multiple `postalCode`.

To obtain the `postalCode`, you need to be more specific like for example **writing the street**.

Comment: That makes sense but there is a `CLLocation` returned with a specific longitude & latitude. Why would it not return the postal code associated with that? That would be useful in many instances.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now. So I added the following to get zip code for the placemark:             CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:placemark.region.center.latitude longitude:placemark.region.center.longitude];
            [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:loc completionHandler:
             ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                 if ([placemarks count] > 0)
                 {
                     [self setUserLocation:[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]];
                     
                 }
             }];

Comment: i did this but still no postalCode is found. I Loged the whole placemarker returned by the completionHandler and searches for the key postalCode and also for zipCode, but not a single entity is found.